# Mockito cannot mock this class: interface org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCache

Tags: class, mocking, mockito, this

I need to mock RemoteCache.class (org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCache) in one of my unit test. When I use following statement, I get "Mockito cannot mock this class: interface org.infinispan.client.hotrod.RemoteCache" error.

RemoteCache<Object, Object> mockRemoteCache = Mockito.mock(RemoteCache.class);

What is wrong with it?

This is the code block I want to test:

```
public Object putCache(String mapName, String key, Object value) {
    Object result = new Object();
    try {
        result = remoteCacheManager.getCache(mapName).put(key, value);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is the test code I am trying:

```
public void testPutCache() {
    DataGridServiceImpl mockDataGridService = Mockito.mock(DataGridServiceImpl.class);

    Mockito.when(mockDataGridService.putCache(anyString(), anyString(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(new Object());

    Object cache = mockDataGridService.putCache(mapName, cacheName, value);

    Assert.assertNotNull(cache);

    RemoteCacheManager mockRemoteCacheManager = Mockito.mock(RemoteCacheManager.class);
        
    mockDataGridService.setRemoteCacheManager(mockRemoteCacheManager);

    RemoteCache<Object, Object> mockRemoteCache = Mockito.mock(RemoteCache.class);

Mockito.when(mockRemoteCacheManager.getCache(anyString())).thenReturn(mockRemoteCache);  

Mockito.when(mockRemoteCacheManager.getCache(anyString()).put(anyString(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(new Object());

    cache = mockRemoteCacheManager.getCache(mapName).put(cacheName, value);

    Assert.assertNotNull(cache);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say about Spring/Spring Boot and Java versions.
Anyway, often this error appears when the problem is in the wrong Mockito version.
I think you can try up mockito version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```